# Count pages in PCL with GhostPDL 9.x

Tags: ghostscript, printer-control-language

I used to Count pages in a pcl file using the GhostPDL (pcl6.exe) in Version 8.71.

```
pcl6.exe -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=nullpage -g10x10 -C file.prn
```

which produced a

```
%%PageCount: 10
```

for instance. Now I updated to 9.10 Version and found that my usual code did not work anymore. The command line Switch "-C" is gone.

I searched the documentation but it brought me nowwhere close to a solution. So it does not seems a very good approach to convert PCL to PDF and then count the PDF pages with GhostScript.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why is converting to a PDF and then using pdfinfo not a good solution ?

Comment: The PCL maintainer says you can use -sDEVICE=bbox and count the number of output lines.